# MongoError: cannot nest $ under $in

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to query multiple documents that have a pair of `basename` and `entries`, while `entries` is an array containing a field called `crc`.

Example of 2 item2:

```
{
  "basename": "2020bb",
  "entries": [
    {
      "name": "030-c1.bin",
      "extension": "bin",
      "basename": "030-c1",
      "crc": "4f5e19bd",
      "size": 1048576
    },
    {
      "name": "030-c2.bin",
      "extension": "bin",
      "basename": "030-c2",
      "crc": "d6314bf0",
      "size": 1048576
    },
    {
      "name": "030-c3.bin",
      "extension": "bin",
      "basename": "030-c3",
      "crc": "47fddfee",
      "size": 1048576
    }
  ]
},
{
  "basename": "mutnat",
  "entries": [
    {
      "name": "sp-s2.sp1",
      "extension": "sp1",
      "basename": "sp-s2",
      "crc": "9036d879",
      "size": 1048576
    },
    {
      "name": "sp-s3.sp1",
      "extension": "sp1",
      "basename": "sp-s3",
      "crc": "c7f2fa45",
      "size": 1048576
    },
    {
      "name": "sp-4.sp1",
      "extension": "sp1",
      "basename": "sp-s4",
      "crc": "e72943de",
      "size": 1048576
    }
  ]
}
```

I know the `basename`s and `crc`s and I am trying to find many items containing proper pairs. For this I am using `$in`, `$all` and `$elemMatch`

```
{
  "basename": {
    "$in": [
      "2020bb",
      "mutnat"
    ]
  },
  "entries": {
    "$in": [
      {
        "$all": [
          { "$elemMatch": { "crc": "4f5e19bd" } },
          { "$elemMatch": { "crc": "d6314bf0" } },
          { "$elemMatch": { "crc": "47fddfee" } }
        ]
      },
      {
        "$all": [
          { "$elemMatch": { "crc": "9036d879" } },
          { "$elemMatch": { "crc": "c7f2fa45" } },
          { "$elemMatch": { "crc": "e72943de" } }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Mind that *just for the brievety of this example* I only have one item inside the `$in`s. In reality there are multiple items in these arrays.

With this query however I get this error:

> `MongoError: cannot nest $ under $in`

*edit: clarified my data and my query*

Answer (score 0):

```
db.xxx.find({
  "basename": "2020bb",
  "entries": {
     $elemMatch: {
       "crc": { $in: ["4f5e19bd", "d6314bf0", "47fddfee" ] }
     }
   }
})
```

Comment: the thing is, I need to query multiple items that each consist of a `basename` and `entries`

Comment: In this case I think it would suffice to just do “basename”: { $in: […] } and do $in (behaves like or ) or $all for “crc”s depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Can you elaborate? Because that is just what I tried to do and I got the error above

Comment: I think you used $all before elemMatch while elemMatch allows queries. In my code above try to replace $in with $all if you need all matched.

Comment: I clarified my data and my query. the thing is that I need to match many ($in) different combinations of `basename` and `entries`